# React TypeScript & ForwardRef - Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

After dropping quite some time fighting with typings and forwardRefs in React and TypeScript, I am hoping somebody else can clear this up for me.

I am building a DataList component which is comprised of three pieces:

- Container to hold all event listeners and logic
- List itself, a `ul`
- List item, an `li`

Ultimately, the usage would look like this:

```
<DataList.List ...>
  <DataList.Item ...>content</DataList.Item>
</DataList.List>
```

To achieve the functionality I need, I am leveraging React.forwardRef, but have found this difficult with TypeScript as I struggle correctly typing the components to receive a `ref` as well as `children` and additional props.

**DataListContainer**
I essentially want this component to just handle logic and event listeners while returning the primary DataList component (shown next). But the key here, is that I need to create the DataList ref here and assign it to the returned component.

```
const DataListContainer: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const listRef = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);

  return (
      <DataList ref={listRef}>{children}</DataList>
  );
};
```

**DataList**
I want the DataList component to just handle its UI and props.

```
interface Props extends TestId {
  focusedItemId?: string;
}

const DataList: React.FC<Props> = React.forwardRef<HTMLUListElement, Props>(
  ({ children, focusedItemId, testId }, ref) => {
    return (
      <ul
        aria-activedescendant={focusedItemId}
        data-test-id={testId}
        ref={ref}
      >
        {children}
      </ul>
    );
  },
);
```

This isn't quite right, though. As This setup gives me the error

```
Type '{ children: any[]; ref: RefObject<HTMLUListElement>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there! Following [React TypeScript Cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forward_and_create_ref/) the problem is with `DataList` props. Adding children prop would fix it

```js
interface Props extends TestId {
  children?: ReactNode;
  focusedItemId?: string;
}
```

I have recreated a simple example in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-beaver-7nbk7?file=/src/App.tsx)